# How does webpack v4 handle devDependencies in production mode?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader

I'm wondering how does webpack handle `devDependencies` when in production mode:

**App.js**

```
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader';

function App() {
  // App code
}

export default process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? hot(module)(App) : App;
```

I can successfully use a ternary into the `export` statement. But I can't do that and neither set a condition in the `import` statement.

**QUESTION**

What is the proper way to handle this (the import of a devDependency)?

Will webpack add `devDependencies` to the bundle if no condition is placed at the import?

---

**EDIT:**

Just found out that webpack **does add** `devDependencies` to the bundle:

This was generated with webpack `mode` set to `production`:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it with [ignorePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin)

**App.js**

```
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader'; 

function App() {
  // App code
}

export default process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? hot(module)(App) : App;
```

**webpack.prod.js** (webpack production config file)

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',

  plugins:[
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/react-hot-loader/),  // <------ WILL IGNORE THE react-hot-loader
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
  ],
```

[image]

This way `react-hot-loader` is ignored in production mode.

In development I use another config file for webpack, which doesn't use the ignorePlugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two new files for app, `app.dev.js` and `app.prod.js` while in app you just switch the require based on env.

```
// App.js
let App;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  App = require('./app.dev.js')
} else {
  App = require('./app.prod.js')
}
export default App
```

EDIT:

It's essential that require is used instead of import as only require can be used dynamically like this.

Comment: Can I do that with `import` instead of `require`?

Comment: you can't use `import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader'` as it's not dynamic. You could use the dynamic `import()` if your app is set up to use it but it's still experimental https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import